# ¿Cómo generar un bucle para adición de filas?

Tags: r, bucles, rstudio

Estoy aprendiendo a trabajar con bucles en R y tengo la siguiente duda:

Estoy trabajando con el siguiente dataframe a modo de ejemplo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito generar un bucle que compruebe el valor de "REPE", y si este es superior a 1 añada una fila al final del dataframe. Esta fila debe ser igual a la que analizo pero con el valor REPE-1, al mismo tiempo tengo que sustituir el valor de la columna REPE de la fila analizada al valor 1.

De esta forma por ejemplo (al ejecutar el bucle tres veces) estaría desglosando la fila que corresponde a ANA en cuatro filas, dejando el valor 1 en la columna REPE en cada una de las filas.

Quiero generar un bucle que haga algo asi con todas las filas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mediante código para no tener que chequear fila a fila.

Comment: Bienvenida Marta a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Answer (score 0):

Si no te entendí mal, te puedo sugerir usar directamente la función `rep()` que sirve justamente para generar repeticiones. Supongamos estos datos:

```
df <- data.frame(NOMBRE = c('MARTA', 'ANA', 'JUAN', 'PEPE', 'ELSE', 'ALICIA'),
                 REPE = c(1, 4, 2, 8, 1, 2))
```

Podemos generar un nuevo `data.frame`:

```
data.frame(NOMBRE = rep(df$NOMBRE, df$REPE),
           REPE = 1)

   NOMBRE REPE
1   MARTA    1
2     ANA    1
3     ANA    1
4     ANA    1
5     ANA    1
6    JUAN    1
7    JUAN    1
8    PEPE    1
9    PEPE    1
10   PEPE    1
11   PEPE    1
12   PEPE    1
13   PEPE    1
14   PEPE    1
15   PEPE    1
16   ELSE    1
17 ALICIA    1
18 ALICIA    1
```

Comment: Genial! Era justo lo que estaba buscando! Mil gracias :)